Resolving all subdomains of a domain for local development of a web app which uses wildcard DNS
I'm working on a web application, and one aspect of our application is that it sets up a subdomain for each customer.  On production this is implemented with wildcard DNS, so that .example.com hits our public load balancer.
For local development, I've been making do with manual edits to /etc/hosts, but that gets tedious to keep adding more and more entries over time as I test new features which require setting up new customers.  /etc/hosts does not support wildcards, unfortunately, or I would have done that a long time ago :)
I'd like to set up a local DNS resolver, such as dnsmasq (though I'm open to other suggestions) that has a wildcard DNS entry.  For example, I'd like to have it set up so that .example.docker resolves to 127.0.0.1.
I've tried installing dnsmasq and adding the line address=/example.docker/127.0.0.1 to the config, but that doesn't work.
An additional complication: we use Twingate for accessing remote servers over a VPN-like connection, and whatever solution I come up with here needs to not interfere with that.  I don't know how Twingate DNS resolution works.
I'll be honest, I'm not sure how DNS resolution works on modern Ubuntu, which is probably part of my struggle.  For example, this question suggests editing /etc/resolv.conf, but any change I make there gets overwritten by NetworkManager.  I don't want to break normal DNS resolution (so, for example, when I connect to a new Wi-Fi network, normal DNS queries hit the DHCP-provided DNS server), but everything I've tried so far seems to be either dnsmasq OR "normal resolution" -- I haven't figured out how to make them play nicely with each other.

I ended up finding another post online with instructions on how to configure dnsmasq for answering *.docker, and configuring systemd-resolved to use the localhost dnsmasq for all *.docker domains.  This works well enough for my use case.
In /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/docker.conf:
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
Domains=~docker

In /etc/dnsmasq.d/docker.conf:
bind-interfaces
address=/docker/127.0.0.1
no-resolv

This has the nice benefit of only treating the *.docker domains specially, and systemd-resolved continues doing its previous "systemd black magic wizardry" for all other DNS resolution.
